# Variation in number of zeros of a continuous function with respect to a parameter

Tags: continuity, roots

Let $f_{\lambda}$ be a continuous function defined on a compact set $K$, which also depends on a parameter $\lambda$ in a continuous manner. Suppose that for $\lambda=0$, the function $f_0$ has $n$ zeros. Does it follow that for small $\lambda$, the function $f_\lambda$ also has $n$ zeros?

Comment: Are you working over the reals or the complex? If you take the reals, then this already doesn't work for $f_{\lambda}(x)=x^2 + \lambda$. For $\lambda=0$ we have 1 zero (respectively 2 if counted with multiplicity), but for negative lambda there are no zeros at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take $f_\lambda(x) = x + \lambda$ on the unit interval. Then $f_0$ has one zero, namely $x=0$, but $f_\lambda(x) \ge \lambda$ has no zeros for all $\lambda > 0$.

Comment: Perhaps, we can show that this number can only decrease in a small neighbourhood of $\lambda$.

Comment: @TanujDipshikha. Quite possibly. I will have to sleep on it. It is quite late in my timezone.

Comment: @TanujDipshikha. I am not sure, but another example which may be relevant to you is $f_\lambda(x) = \lambda \sin(x)$ on the interval $[0,2 \pi]$. For $\lambda > 0$ there is exactly $3$ zeros, while $f_0(x) = 0$ for all $x$.